# Calculating average pixel value for each band across multiple raster layers?

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterstats

[image]

I have a set of raster files that are essentially data sets of precipitation across a region. I have multiple raster files that are the outputs of different climate models. Each pixel in the raster file has 365 bands that represent the precipitation value for each day. I want to calculate the mean for each pixel for each band across the different raster files.

I tried converting the raster to point files and extracting multiple values to the point, extracting the data to excel and then averaging them for each raster. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: *the mean for each pixel for each band* has no sense for me

Comment: So each raster (of which there are many) has 365 "bands" which represent the rainfall for that pixel for each day of the year. So you are looking to get the average rainfall for a pixel per model (raster)?

Comment: Some illustration, a table, a graphic would sure help to make the question clearer.

Comment: @Techie_Gus Ive updated the question witha figure.... Is the question clearer?

Comment: @aldo_tapia Yes and no. Each raster has 365 bands that represent the precipitation for each day. I am looking to average the rainfall for each pixel across all raster for each band.

Comment: Check https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/222293/80215

Comment: To make sure I got this right, if you have 3 different climate models, for each model there is a raster band for each day. So basically, for 1 pixel you will have 365 x 3 values. Right?

Comment: @Techie_Gus Yes. Each pixel will have 365 values for each raster. I want to generate an output raster where that pixel is the average of the rainfall values from the 3 models.

Comment: @aldo_tapia Thank you, that seems like it does part of the analysis i want to conduct but I have zero experience in R, I was wondering if this can be done using arcpy or model builder or with MATLAB.

Comment: @KeaganAllan Yes and no. Each raster has 365 bands that represent the precipitation for each day. I am looking to average the rainfall for each pixel across all raster for each band. So for example lets say i have pixel 1 in 3 raster. Each pixel from each raster has the data for the 365 days. What i want to do is to average the rainfall value across all 3 models for each day, so that i can generate a pixel with 365 data points again but the values are that of the average across all the rasters.

Comment: @Mukunth Natarajan did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue with different data.

Comment: R: raster::calc(x, mean)

Comment: You could translate the raster into points for each layer, triangulate them, to get a spatial  relation between the points and recalculate the raster for each layer with a synchroneous ratser setting, using an interpolation method like Inverse Distance Weightening (IDW). Aftermath the statisical part could be applied.

Comment: I think you should consider using python with gdal and numpy to solve your problem.

Comment: You can use cell statistics in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

There are many raster calculators available. Depends, what software you are familiar with.

E.g. you can use [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass79/manuals/r.series.html) `r.series` module (the module is also accessible via [QGIS](https://qgis.org) toolbox).

As @mdsumner commented, you can also use R.

A programatic approach is to read data by [Python Numpy](https://numpy.org/) and calculate desired statistics. Numpy methods are also implemented in the command line by [gdal_calc.py](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_calc.html).

If data is in NetCDF (typical format for climate/meteo time-series data), you can process with some of [these tools](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html) (I can mention e.g. [NCO](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/software.html#NCO))

In case of precipitation, maybe there is some purpose of averaging of daily data (compare 3 different datasources?). Maybe some other statistics (e.g. sum, max) could be considered.