# Extracting mean of multiple SpatRasters using Terra?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I have a list of rasters which I want to combine into a single raster by getting the mean for each cell, ideally in the R `terra` package. According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222291/extracting-mean-of-multiple-raster-layers-using-r/222293#222293) answer, the `calc` function in the `raster` package can be used to do this, but this won't take the `SpatRaster` objects from `terra` as arguments. Is there an equivalent method in `terra`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The terra equivalent of `raster::calc` is `terra::app` so, to return the mean for a multi-band raster you would use:

`rmean <- app(x, mean)`

or to return the mean for an entire raster:

`global(x, mean)`.

Comment: To clarify, if my rasters are `r1`, `r2` and `r3`. Should I set `x` to be `c(r1,r2,r3)`, or should `x` be `rast(c(r1,r2,r3))`?

Comment: @A.Bollans If `r1` to `r3` are raster files, use `c(r1,r2,r3)`. If it are filenames, use `rast(c(r1,r2,r3))`