# Counting number of observations per pixel in a rasterstack

Tags: raster, r

I have a rasterstack of satellite derived chlorophyll data in the Southern Ocean, and due to cloud cover etc there is a great deal of variation in the number of observations per pixel. How do I compute the number of chlorophyll observations per pixel in a stack and plot this on a map? Days without observations are indicated as NA. So essentially I want to count the number of times a pixel is NA in a raster stack.

I have tried running this function:

```
Chl.obs <- function(x, t = 0) { return( length(x[x > t]) ) }
```

But what I get is a plot with the total number of observations and not a map showing a count of populated pixels. When I use this function and change all NA values to 0 on a single layer it seems to work fine but I cannot apply `Y2020ML[is.na(Y2020ML)] <- 0` to large raster stacks for some reason.

In other words, I have been calculating means and SD for raster stacks and I want to know how to create a plot of the sample size (N) that has gone into computing those statistics. How many observations have been used for each pixel mean

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting mean of multiple raster layers using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222291/extracting-mean-of-multiple-raster-layers-using-r)

Comment: I have tried running this function:                                                                         
Chl.obs <- function(x, t = 0) { 
  return( length(x[x > t]) )                                                                                                                      
} But what I get is a plot with the total number of observations and not a map showing a count of populated pixels. When I use this function and change all NA values to 0 on a single layer it seems to work fine but I cannot apply Y2020ML[is.na(Y2020ML)] <- 0 to large raster stacks for some reason.

Comment: In other words, I have been calculating means and SD for raster stacks and I want to know how to create a plot of the sample size (N) that has gone into computing those statistics. How many observations have been used for each pixel mean.

Comment: You should add the information in your comments to your post. Relevant information like what you have tried and any errors should be in your post. You can use the Edit function at bottom of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(terra)

# Create rasters for example
# Basic raster
r1 <- rast(ncol=2,nrow=2)                 
# Assign values to raster cells. Notice I put an NA in one.
r1[] <- c(NA,2,3,4)  

# Second raster to make a small stack. 
r2 <- rast(ncol=2,nrow=2)
r2[] <- c(6,1,1,1)   

# Combine the raster, what you call a stack in the raster package.
r3 <- c(r1,r2)

# Values for each layer. The count for layer 1 sums to 3 because of the NA
> freq(r3)
  layer value count
1     1     2     1
2     1     3     1
3     1     4     1
4     2     1     3
5     2     6     1

# This will county the cells by layer that are not NA.
# Creates one new layer from the two 
ex3 <- app(r3, function(x) sum(!is.na(x)))

# Values across the pixels in the new raster
> freq(ex3)
  layer value count
1     1     1     1
2     1     2     3
```

This is what the output looks like as raster plot.

[image]

So you can see that by summing the `!is.na()` with `app`, we get two across the cells that didn't have NA, as expected, and one for the cell that has an NA in layer one.

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
library(terra)
s <- rast(ncol=10, nrow=10, nlyr=5)
set.seed(0)
values(s) <- sample(c(1:4, NA), size(s), replace=TRUE)
```

You can count the NAs like this

```
sna <- sum(is.na(s))
```

And with terra version 1.7-21 you can also do

```
sna <- countNA(s)
```